# No backports error while retraining Tensorflow's Inception v3 model

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been trying to retrain Inception by following the tutorial here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining.
I get this error "No module named backports"
when I run this

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir ~/marine_animal_species1
```

This is the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "/home/karthik/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 91, in <module>
        import tensorflow as tf
      File "/home/karthik/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import *
      File "/home/karthik/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *
      File "/home/karthik/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 100, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.framework.subscribe import subscribe
      File "/home/karthik/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/subscribe.py", line 26, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.ops import variables
      File "/home/karthik/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 26, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
      File "/home/karthik/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 70, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
      File "/home/karthik/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 33, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.util import tf_should_use
      File "/home/karthik/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 28, in <module>
        from backports import weakref  # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
    ImportError: No module named backports
```

I use ubuntu 16.04.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo pip install backports.weakref
sudo pip3 install backports.weakref
```

Solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install the weakref module from the backports namespace.
You can get the wheel file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.weakref/1.0rc1 & install the downloaded wheel as such:

```
sudo pip install backports.weakref-1.0rc1-py2-none-any.whl # python2
sudo pip3 install backports.weakref-1.0rc1-py3-none-any.whl # python3
```

Then run your command

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/...
```

This should solve your problem.